# Can't get solutions in output of wolfram mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When I type a function into wolfram mathematica (such as EulerEquations[]) it doesn't output a solution, just outputs the same thing I typed in as input.

[image: Example]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

`EulerEquations[f,y[x],x]` will return the Euler-Lagrange differential equation obeyed from `y[x]`. You'll probably recall these are associated with a variational problem for the functional f. Try entering `Dsolve[%,y[x],x]` to get the solution, if that's what you're after.

Also, you may need to load the package Needs["VariationalMethods`"], especially if you're working directly in Mathematica and not on Alpha.

[image]

Comment: @cadams was this at all helpful? I'm pretty familiar with EL equations in general, or with numerical solutions if dsolve doesn't work for you. Best wishes.